# Apache Nutch 2.3.1 fetching error

Tags: java, apache, hbase, nutch

I am trying to crawl an entire website and anticipated a large amount of urls. Because of this I set the number of rounds in my apache nutch crawl to 5 and then ran the crawl. The crawl is now in the 3rd round and is still fetching urls fine, but in the log file I see this:

> fetching *url name that was fetched* (queue crawl delay=5000ms) 50/50
>   spinwaiting/active, 949 pages, 2 errors, 0.2 0 pages/s, 26 17 kb/s,
>   2500 URLs in 1 queues

how can I find out what the two errors are? I see this error underneath hundreds of urls that were fetched. I am using apache nutch 2.3.1 and hbase 0.94. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check your log files for your errors, some error occurs because of your slow Internet connections or timeout (max) issue. Check your logs for details